# why if else doesn't respond in c

Tags: c

when grossPay pass into find tax amount,seem like tax if else doesn't receive it...result is 0.0000
how can i solve this??

```
float grossPay = 400;


float taxPhase1 = 0;
float taxPhase2 = 0;
float taxPhase3 = 0;
float totalTax = 0;

if(grossPay<=300)
{
    taxPhase1 = ((float)(grossPay)*(15/100));
    totalTax = taxPhase1;
}
else if(grossPay>300 && grossPay<=450)
{
    taxPhase1 = ((float)300*(15/100));
    taxPhase2 = ((float)(grossPay-300)*(20/100));
    totalTax = (taxPhase1 + taxPhase2);
}

else if(grossPay>450)
{
    taxPhase1 = ((float)300*(15/100));
    taxPhase2 = ((float)150*(20/100));
    taxPhase3 = ((float)(grossPay-450)*(25/100));
    totalTax = (taxPhase1 + taxPhase2 + taxPhase3) ;
}

  printf("%f",totalTax);
```

Comment: There are no fuction calls except `printf` in this code. Please post [mcve].

Comment: sorry my bad..i'm new here .actually i have no idea how to ask it..if you can help me out,highly appreciate.@EugeneSh.

Comment: To avoid integer division rounding error, suggest changing `15/100` to `15.0/100.0` (everywhere it applies)

Comment: You are using integer division such as `15/100` which is resulting in `0`. Convert it to floating point by writing something like `15.0/100`

Comment: To make this complete you could wrap it in `int main(void) { //your code here... return 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has several instances of integer division errors such as:

```
15/100
```

Which all result in zero, resulting in incorrect evaluations

```
taxPhase1 = ((float)(grossPay)*(15/100));//result == 0
```

Change to

```
15.0/100  or 15/100.0 (for all occurrences.)

taxPhase1 = ((float)(grossPay)*(15/100.0));//result = 60.0 (gross pay == 400)
```